# Term of the upper central series

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G$) be the center of G. The upper central series
$1=Z_0(G)≤Z_1(G)≤…,$ is defined by $Z_{n+1}(G)/Z_n(G)=Z(G/Z_n(G))$.

Let $Z_n(G)$ be $n^{th}$ term of the upper central serie of a group $G$.

My question is: I can affirm that $Z_n(G)$ is a nilpotent group of class $\leq n$? If yes, Why?

Comment: Because $Z_i(G)$ is a central series for $Z_n(G)$ of length $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use induction on $n$ and notice that if $Z(G)\leq H\leq G$ then $Z(G)\leq Z(H)$.